# Can't override css because of wmuslider js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I got this responsive template by w3layouts

https://w3layouts.com/design-lab-interior-category-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

And I started to try to tweak the design and add my own elements, but whenever I try to add my own css on my elements in the slider section (Clients), it doesn't apply and because of the `jquery.wmuSlider.js` file, as whenever I remove linking this file or stop executing the function `wmuSlider()` in it, the section doesn't even show.

Anyone have an idea why this file preventing me from overriding the css in this section unless I tweaked the existing css `.clients p` and `.clients h4`?

the jquery.wmuSlider.js file

```js
/*!
 * jQuery wmuSlider v2.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Brice Lechatellier
 * http://brice.lechatellier.com/
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

;(function($) {

  $.fn.wmuSlider = function(options) {

    /* Default Options
        ================================================== */
    var defaults = {
      animation: 'fade',
      animationDuration: 600,
      slideshow: true,
      slideshowSpeed: 7000,
      slideToStart: 0,
      navigationControl: true,
      paginationControl: true,
      previousText: 'Previous',
      nextText: 'Next',
      touch: false,
      slide: 'article',
      items: 1
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

      /* Variables
            ================================================== */
      var $this = $(this);
      var currentIndex = options.slideToStart;
      var wrapper = $this.find('.wmuSliderWrapper');
      var slides = $this.find(options.slide);
      var slidesCount = slides.length;
      var slideshowTimeout;
      var paginationControl;
      var isAnimating;


      /* Load Slide
            ================================================== */
      var loadSlide = function(index, infinite, touch) {
        if (isAnimating) {
          return false;
        }
        isAnimating = true;
        currentIndex = index;
        var slide = $(slides[index]);
        $this.animate({ height: slide.innerHeight() });
        if (options.animation == 'fade') {
          slides.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            opacity: 0
          });
          slide.css('position', 'relative');
          slide.animate({ opacity:1 }, options.animationDuration, function() {
            isAnimating = false;
          });
        } else if (options.animation == 'slide') {
          if (!infinite) {
            wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * index }, options.animationDuration, function() {
              isAnimating = false;
            });
          } else {
            if (index == 0) {
              wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * slidesCount }, options.animationDuration, function() {
                wrapper.css('marginLeft', 0);
                isAnimating = false;
              });
            } else {
              if (!touch) {
                wrapper.css('marginLeft', -$this.width() / options.items * slidesCount);
              }
              wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * index }, options.animationDuration, function() {
                isAnimating = false;
              });
            }
          }
        }

        if (paginationControl) {
          paginationControl.find('a').each(function(i) {
            if(i == index) {
              $(this).addClass('wmuActive');
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('wmuActive');
            }
          });
        }

        // Trigger Event
        $this.trigger('slideLoaded', index);
      };


      /* Navigation Control
            ================================================== */
      /*--  if (options.navigationControl) {
                var prev = $('<a class="wmuSliderPrev">' + options.previousText + '</a>');
                prev.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
                    if (currentIndex == 0) {
                        loadSlide(slidesCount - 1, true);
                    } else {
                        loadSlide(currentIndex - 1);
                    }
                });
                $this.append(prev);

                var next = $('<a class="wmuSliderNext">' + options.nextText + '</a>');
                next.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
                    if (currentIndex + 1 == slidesCount) {
                        loadSlide(0, true);
                    } else {
                        loadSlide(currentIndex + 1);
                    }
                });
                $this.append(next);
            }
         --*/

      /* Pagination Control
            ================================================== */
      if (options.paginationControl) {
        paginationControl = $('<ul class="wmuSliderPagination"></ul>');
        $.each(slides, function(i) {
          paginationControl.append('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>');
          paginationControl.find('a:eq(' + i + ')').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
            loadSlide(i);
          });
        });
        $this.append(paginationControl);
      }


      /* Slideshow
            ================================================== */
      if (options.slideshow) {
        var slideshow = function() {
          if (currentIndex + 1 < slidesCount) {
            loadSlide(currentIndex + 1);
          } else {
            loadSlide(0, true);
          }
          slideshowTimeout = setTimeout(slideshow, options.slideshowSpeed);
        }
        slideshowTimeout = setTimeout(slideshow, options.slideshowSpeed);
      }


      /* Resize Slider
            ================================================== */
      var resize = function() {
        var slide = $(slides[currentIndex]);
        $this.animate({ height: slide.innerHeight() });
        if (options.animation == 'slide') {
          slides.css({
            width: $this.width() / options.items
          });
          wrapper.css({
            marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * currentIndex,
            width: $this.width() * slides.length
          });
        }
      };


      /* Touch
            ================================================== */
      var touchSwipe = function(event, phase, direction, distance) {
        clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
        if(phase == 'move' && (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right')) {
          if (direction == 'right') {
            if (currentIndex == 0) {
              wrapper.css('marginLeft', (-slidesCount * $this.width() / options.items) + distance);
            } else {
              wrapper.css('marginLeft', (-currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items) + distance);
            }
          } else if (direction == 'left') {
            wrapper.css('marginLeft', (-currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items) - distance);
          }
        } else if (phase == 'cancel' ) {
          if (direction == 'right' && currentIndex == 0) {
            wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -slidesCount * $this.width() / options.items }, options.animationDuration);
          } else {
            wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items }, options.animationDuration);
          }
        } else if (phase == 'end' ) {
          if (direction == 'right') {
            if (currentIndex == 0) {
              loadSlide(slidesCount - 1, true, true);
            } else {
              loadSlide(currentIndex - 1);
            }
          } else if (direction == 'left')    {
            if (currentIndex + 1 == slidesCount) {
              loadSlide(0, true);
            } else {
              loadSlide(currentIndex + 1);
            }
          } else {
            wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items }, options.animationDuration);
          }
        }
      };
      if (options.touch && options.animation == 'slide') {
        if (!$.isFunction($.fn.swipe)) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'jquery.touchSwipe.min.js',
            async: false
          });
        }
        if ($.isFunction($.fn.swipe)) {
          $this.swipe({ triggerOnTouchEnd:false, swipeStatus:touchSwipe, allowPageScroll:'vertical' });
        }
      }


      /* Init Slider
            ================================================== */
      var init = function() {
        var slide = $(slides[currentIndex]);
        var img = slide.find('img');
        img.load(function() {
          wrapper.show();
          $this.animate({ height: slide.innerHeight() });
        });
        if (options.animation == 'fade') {
          slides.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            opacity: 0

          });
          $(slides[currentIndex]).css('position', 'relative');
        } else if (options.animation == 'slide') {
          if (options.items > slidesCount) {
            options.items = slidesCount;
          }
          slides.css('float', 'left');
          slides.each(function(i){
            var slide = $(this);
            slide.attr('data-index', i);
          });
          for(var i = 0; i < options.items; i++) {
            wrapper.append($(slides[i]).clone());
          }
          slides = $this.find(options.slide);
        }
        resize();

        $this.trigger('hasLoaded');

        loadSlide(currentIndex);
      }
      init();


      /* Bind Events
            ================================================== */
      // Resize
      $(window).resize(resize);

      // Load Slide
      $this.bind('loadSlide', function(e, i) {
        clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
        loadSlide(i);
      });

    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.midh3{
  direction: rtl !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #f45f42 !important;
}

.clients p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;
}
/*.clients  p {
    background: url(../images/quote.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: 24px;
}*/
.clients h4{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:25px;
  direction: rtl;
  color:#f45f42;
  margin:15px 0 10px 0;
}
.clients h5{
  text-align:left;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#999;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.wmuSlider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#clients {
    padding-bottom: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wmuSlider example1 animated wow slideInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s">
  <div class="wmuSliderWrapper">
    <article style="position: absolute; width: 100%; opacity: 0;">
      <div class="banner-wrap">
        <div class="col-md-4 client-grids">
          <p>In vitae tincidunt turpis. Proin in euismod dolor. Sed eget tellus venenatis, molestie lorem tempus, viverra ante vulputate.</p>
          <div class="col-md-5 c-img">
            <img src="images/c1.jpg"  alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 c-info">
            <h4>Jackie</h4>
            <h5>Businss man</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 client-grids">
          <p>In vitae tincidunt turpis. Proin in euismod dolor. Sed eget tellus venenatis, molestie lorem tempus, viverra ante vulputate.</p>
          <div class="col-md-5 c-img">
            <img src="images/c2.jpg"  alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 c-info">
            <h4>Charlize</h4>
            <h5>Teacher</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 client-grids">
          <p>In vitae tincidunt turpis. Proin in euismod dolor. Sed eget tellus venenatis, molestie lorem tempus, viverra ante vulputate.</p>
          <div class="col-md-5 c-img">
            <img src="images/c3.jpg"  alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 c-info">
            <h4>Jessica</h4>
            <h5>Engineer</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article style="position: absolute; width: 100%; opacity: 0;">
      <div class="banner-wrap">
        <div class="col-md-4 client-grids">
          <h3 class="midh3">my style</h3>

          <p>my paragragh</p>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 client-grids">
          <p>In vitae tincidunt turpis. Proin in euismod dolor. Sed eget tellus venenatis, molestie lorem tempus, viverra ante vulputate.</p>
          <div class="col-md-5 c-img">
            <img src="images/c2.jpg"  alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 c-info">
            <h4>Johnson</h4>
            <h5>Teacher</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 client-grids">
          <p>In vitae tincidunt turpis. Proin in euismod dolor. Sed eget tellus venenatis, molestie lorem tempus, viverra ante vulputate.</p>
          <div class="col-md-5 c-img">
            <img src="images/c1.jpg"  alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 c-info">
            <h4>Scarllet</h4>
            <h5>Businss man</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </article>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.wmuSlider.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.example1').wmuSlider();
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the !important tag to your css? it will tell the browser override any other matching styles tht may already be set.

Comment: There is no `.clients` in your markdown... An none either, after the script ran.

Comment: Try `.wmuSlider` instead of `.clients`... Seems to work perfectly [on this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vdmZPZ).